# Fixed point of the SHA-256 compression function

Tags: collision-resistance, sha-256

SHA256 Free Start Self Collision (Full 64 rounds)

IVec:

```
72BF9EF1 27B82DFB F298F3B7 22B6C32C 18A54860 4C032D91 ADD7B85B 7ED1A4AC
```

Block:

```
0000004D 0000006F 00000075 00000073 00000065 00000054 00000072 00000061
00000070 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000080 00000000 000001B8
```

Output:

```
72BF9EF1 27B82DFB F298F3B7 22B6C32C 18A54860 4C032D91 ADD7B85B 7ED1A4AC
```

http://modalisengineering.com/crypt/sha256mt.c

Is this an issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's correct? Because I tried to put your result on some online calculator and it didn't work out. It gave me the result: 2682018704b04208c8144dce2e43a3cf71f007230b5e3ac5b4aa6f5774f81830. Maybe I misunderstood - I put IV and concatenated the block - was that what you meant?

Comment: The IVEC is not part of the data block.  The link above shows an example C program that allows for the IVEC to be entered on the command line.  Alternatively, edit any publicly available source code and use the above IVEC.  With this example, the input block can be repeated any number of times and the hash value does not change.

Comment: @A.B. You need to look at the compression function, not the full SHA2. It has two inputs, one takes the state from the previous iteration (or the IV on the first block) the other the current block.

Comment: Actually this is more of a fixed point ($f(x)=x$) rather than a collision.

Comment: Actually this is more of a fixed point (f(x)=x).
Right. I'm thinking if a number of such known fixed points will give dangerous insights on SHA256?

Comment: I verified that compressing this (IV, block) pair with SHA256 does indeed reproduce the input IV. How did you find this?

Comment: As a very important check, can you do the same with another IV /block pair?

Comment: @PaulUszak There's are other examples in the linked c code - a full collision on a block that says "NathanMariels" instead of "MouseTrap", and a partial for "MouseTrap"

Comment: Give me a 64 byte block, and I'll give you the IVEC of the zero point

Comment: Link to [gist](https://gist.github.com/back-seat-driver/5704e892b3825a294bccc21cb6a9a0bc) for sha-256 confirmation code

Comment: @Nathan.Mariels @PaulUszak That is an uninteresting question (and trivial to do).  We shouldn't care for the answer `h s.t. compress h m == h` for a fixed message block `m`.  Security implications arise if someone can answer `m s.t. compress h m == h` for a fixed hash context `h`.  And there's no need to ask for an `h` people care about, the initial SHA256 context will do nicely.

Answer (score 34):

SHA-256 is based on a Davies–Meyer compression function. Easy to find fixed-points are a known property of this construction.

> A notable property of the Davies–Meyer construction is that even if the underlying block cipher is totally secure, it is possible to compute [fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) for the construction : for any $m$, one can find a value of $h$ such that $E_m(h) \oplus h = h$ : one just has to set $h = E_m^{-1}(0)$. This is a property that [random functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_function) certainly do not have. So far, no practical attack has been based on this property, but one should be aware of this "feature".
>
> The fixed-points can be used in a second preimage attack (given a message m1, attacker finds another message m2 to satisfy hash(m1) = hash(m2) ) of Kelsey and Schneier for a $2^k$-message-block message in time $3 \cdot 2^{n/2+1}+2^{n-k+1}$. If the construction does not allow easy creation of fixed points (like Matyas–Meyer–Oseas or Miyaguchi–Preneel) then this attack can be done in $k \cdot 2^{n/2+1}+2^{n-k+1}$ time. Note that in both cases the complexity is above $2^{n/2}$ but below $2^n$ when messages are long and that when messages get shorter the complexity of the attack approaches $2^n$.

*(from [One-way compression function - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies.E2.80.93Meyer))*

Thanks to [Samuel Neves](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/592/samuel-neves) for [pointing this out](https://twitter.com/sevenps/status/878609336465055744).

Comment: I don't understand why is this not a full collision? Can't this be made to a practical length extention attack?

Comment: @MeirMaor To abuse this property you need to get the state of the hash to match a state you get when running the decryption of the blockcipher underlying the compression function. Finding such a match requires a meet-in-the-middle attack with cost $2^{n/2}$ and thus isn't cheaper than finding a collision.

Comment: Relevant https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44642/are-there-any-security-issues-when-replacing-the-sha-256-initialisation-values

Comment: @CodesInChaos In the description you posted, the function Em() can be inverted. In the context of the question would Em() be SHA-256? I haven't tried to invert SHA-256 with both IV's and W_t undefined (I will have more degrees of freedom). Inverting the one equation one unknown  mod 2^32 addition isn't completely intuitive.

Comment: @back_seat_driver $E_m$ is SHACAL-2, the block-cipher underlying SHA-2. Practically all blockciphers support efficient decryption. Note that $m$ is the message-block of SHA-2 is used as key in the blockcipher while the IV is used as message.

Answer (score 6):

I found this thread after seeing a similar post on reddit.  It seems the author(s) are making the rounds from here to hacker news to cryptography.reddit.

I was curious if these fixed points could be found with SAT and it turns out the answer is "yes" and extremely quickly.  My comment on reddit is re-produced here.  The portion of interest is at the bottom where I show these fixed points are cheap to find with SAT.

I took a [Cryptol implementation for SHA256](https://github.com/GaloisInc/cryptol/blob/master/examples/MiniLock/prim/SHA256.cry) and added the presented constants:

```
hAttack : [8][32]
hAttack =
  [0xad3381f1, 0x8f9dae20, 0x5419ec4e, 0xc0a9c019, 0x839a030f,
   0xe8bfad5a, 0xd308ae65, 0x3a456ff1]

mAttack : [16][32]
mAttack =
  [0x5b4adf0b, 0xb6373803, 0xdae2f3a9, 0xa951f172, 0xea5ca7b5,
   0x9ce5d74a, 0xce7a52a5, 0xb222cc78, 0xb69c9ed2, 0x60685995,
   0xc5bb23de, 0x1ffe6463, 0xa2c707da, 0xf76ac1c1, 0x71858d71,
   0xc94b58ad]
```

Then the computation is

```
hPostAttack : [8][32]
hPostAttack = SHA256Compress hAttack (SHA256MessageSchedule mAttack)
```

And we're left with the question:

```
SHA256> hPostAttack == hAttack
True
```

For ease of presentation we can define a helper:

```
attackedFunction : [8][32] -> [16][32] -> [8][32]
attackedFunction h m = SHA256Compress h (SHA256MessageSchedule m)
```

And this is a decent point to call out that you can ask a modern SAT solver:

```
:sat \h m -> attackedFunction h m == h
```

Boolector can solve this quickly (while others didn't terminate fast enough for my tastes):

```
(\h m -> attackedFunction h m == h)
  [0x85bc5e5e, 0x3f915388, 0xbdf7d66e, 0x391de59f, 0xf274a8a7,
   0x2cda9e8a, 0x84a49266, 0xaafb7f03]
  [0x914a03b5, 0x43a0873d, 0xbf4839a4, 0x8ee2573a, 0x83b9c634,
   0xce68bdf3, 0x28e46e7d, 0x12121529, 0x3f8cfbb2, 0x1ba42c39,
   0xe9f045cf, 0x6f591416, 0x5219af1d, 0x9f4f98a5, 0x459adb3d,
   0xec7b71c0] = True
```

and

```
(\h m -> attackedFunction h m == h && h != [0x85bc5e5e, 0x3f915388,
                                            0xbdf7d66e, 0x391de59f, 0xf274a8a7, 0x2cda9e8a,
                                            0x84a49266, 0xaafb7f03])
  [0xfbfce142, 0xf1bd9a26, 0x0d57d527, 0xb8ddd0ae, 0xd1393f0a,
   0x53a1c4b4, 0x167dcc03, 0x67ca2e21]
  [0x7ecce350, 0x47b67412, 0x06b2ba9b, 0x13ed7363, 0x6fecd8eb,
   0x03ea043d, 0xf315c864, 0xf9616041, 0x66a269ad, 0x001e71ff,
   0x2ad7cd97, 0x52125bbc, 0x253bc0d6, 0xdb1b6fa6, 0x0e8d5430,
   0x45a9f029] = True
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need a SAT solver; the SHA-256 hash compression function is $hc(state, message) = state \oplus E_{message}(state)$, for an easily invertible (if you know the message) $E$.  All you need to do is take your arbitrary message block and find the state for which $0 = E_{message}(state)$