# Idea behind internal SHA-2 functions

Tags: hash, sha-256, sha-2, compression-function

In the SHA-2 family, specifically SHA-256, there are functions called *Sigma0* and *Sigma1*, which look like this:

```
Sigma0(b, c, d)
{
    Return (b & c) ^ (~b & d);
}
```

I don't really understand the logic or idea behind this. I looked on the internet a lot, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

So does anybody know why they chose this specific function? Is it part of some secure block cipher or permutation algorithm? I couldn't find anything about the *Ch* and *Maj* online, nor what I'm asking now.

Comment: That is too deep. Check this question [What makes SHA256 secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66371/18298).

Comment: Do you mean I have to find another place to ask? I don't really know any...

Comment: Not exactly, The functions are must be considered all together to achieve, the avalanche, confusion, and diffusion...

Comment: [Analyze here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~learnlogic/truthtables/#/true/(b&c)X(!b&d))

Comment: Thanks, so they are just build to be as random as possible and all of them together are "random enough", right?

Comment: True randomness is hard to achieve. What you have seen is the distribution is equal. This is necessary but not sufficient, the input bit may have a correlation with output bits that can be exploited, etc..