# Is there a string that's it's SHA-256 hash is equal to itself?

Tags: hash

Take for example `SHA256`. Is it possible for the hash of a 64 character hex string `S` to be `S`? i.e:
$$H(S)=S$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a string that's hash is equal to itself?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19493/is-there-a-string-thats-hash-is-equal-to-itself) Sights, 37 seconds to find the dupe. Well, apart from the theoretical and demonstrative example, we don't know for secure hashes...

Comment: yes it does, thanks

Comment: +1 for the fast acceptance. Welcome to [cryptography.se]

Comment: Note that there is a limit to file the size on [SHA2 series due to the padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/64716/18298). Therefore there are inputs that cannot be hashed though one cannot calculate such size for hashing. Your title when read alone can be read as this. I've changed the title to fit the body.

Comment: There is such a thing as a "Chameleon hash", where you can cause a collision if you know the private key for a specified public key.