# Does a hash function have a Upper bound on input length?

Tags: hash, sha-1, md5

I came across this [Answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9910/is-it-theoretically-possible-to-construct-a-string-that-contains-its-own-hash-va/9912#9912) stating (just a line from the answer):-

> The input space is "infinite" and thus it has an infinite amount of values that will collide into a single hash

And in the comments of this answer, there exists a comment of @poncho stating:-

> Technically, the input space for the SHA-1 and SHA-2 hash functions is not "infinite"; SHA-1 and SHA-256 inputs are limited to $2^{64}−1$ bits; SHA-512 is limited to $2^{128}−1$ bits

In reply to the above comment, the answer'er does accept the above fact. But, I can't seem to understand why?

As there exists a large number of answers, like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139748/is-my-understanding-of-sha1-correct/139750#139750) who loosely use the term infinite with the input space of hash functions. I tried to resolve the ambiguity via Wikipedia page of [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), this is the definition of both:-

> In cryptography, SHA-1 is a cryptographic hash function which takes an input and produces a 160-bit hash
>
> The MD5 message-digest algorithm is a widely used hash function producing a 128-bit hash value

In both the definition, there exists no mention of input size (in bits) of the algorithms.

**QUESTION:-**
Does hashing algorithms have an upper bound in the input space?

**P.S.:-** If the upper bound does exists, then can anyone tell me why isn't the hashing algorithm able to work on input size above the upper bound?

Comment: Not all hash functions but the universe have a limit on the data to store.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Does hashing algorithms have an upper bound in the input space?

**They can, but they don't have to and it depends on their specification.**

- All Merkle-Damgård based hash functions do have an upper limit, because [appending the message length simplifies the security proof and the backdoor-resistance of the function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1433/23623) and they usually use a fixed-length encoding of the length.
- Though it appears that MD5 ([Spec RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321)) kindof just ignores this and indeed accepts message of infinite length. The encoded length in this case are the low 64 bits (so it's reduced $\bmod 2^{64}$; Thanks to forest for making me actually check).
- SHA-3 ([Spec PDF](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf)) does not have such a limit as it's based on the sponge-construction.
- Skein ([Spec PDF](http://www.skein-hash.info/sites/default/files/skein1.3.pdf)) does have a limit of $2^{96}$ bytes.
- Blake2b ([Spec PDF](https://blake2.net/blake2.pdf)) has a limit of $2^{128}$ bytes.

Comment: Oh, Thanks (+1). I totally forgot the fact that during the process of computing message digest of a message (in **MD5** and **SHA1**), it's original length in bits is appended to the padded bits. Therefore, if we use message length > that length, we won't be able to append the actual length of the original message (as it would either result in **overflow** or would get truncated using a **modulo operation** which would lead to incorrect length).

Comment: BTW could you please tell me why answers like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139748/is-my-understanding-of-sha1-correct/139750#139750) still refer to the input space be infinite in length?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S probably because for most purposes "infinite" is a good approximation of "messages shorter than 2^64 bit" (which is > 1 million terabyte).

Comment: Are you sure MD5 has an upper limit? I seem to recall that the length field was modular and that there was no hard limit, something which Peter Green's answer reinforces.

Comment: @forest I checked and indeed MD5 just uses the lower 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how exactly the hash function is defined.

Typically the first step of a hashing function is to convert the input from a series of bits or bytes to a series of blocks using a padding scheme. Many such padding schemes include the length of the input in the padding as it makes the security arguments easier. Typically the length is encoded as a fixed-size integer.

So the question becomes what happens when the range of that fixed size integer is exceeded. There are two main possibilities.

- The integer is allowed to wrap around (this seems to be the case for MD5)
- The hash function is only defined for messages shorter than a threshold (this seems to be the case for SHA1 and SHA2)

However you are likely to find this is a case where practical implementations of the algorithm don't enforce the specification. For example the first result for "sha1 reference implementation" I found on on google ( https://github.com/clibs/sha1/blob/master/sha1.c ) did not enforce any limit on input size.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info (+1)