# If hash functions append the length, why does length extension attack work?

Tags: hash, merkle-damgaard, length-extension

I have understood that it's trivial to reconstruct the internal state of a hasher for many hash functions, if one only knows the output hash. Then, one can append data after the original data and obtain a valid hash for the original data plus the appended data.

However, recently [I became aware that hash functions including MD5, SHA1, etc. actually append the length](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72069/does-a-hash-function-have-a-upper-bound-on-input-length).

If hash functions append the length, why doesn't that stop the length extension attacks? For a good hash function, if the attacker knows `hash(message || length)`, there should be no way to obtain `hash(message)` to be able to calculate `hash(message || appended_data)` which would allow calculating `hash(message || appended_data || total_length)`.

Related: [Understanding the length extension attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/understanding-the-length-extension-attack) ...although the related question doesn't discuss appending of the length which MD5, SHA1, etc. do.

Comment: what does `hash(message || length)` mean?

Comment: Remember, it's all just bits. Your `message || length` is my `message <that happens to end with length>`.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S `||` is sometimes used to denote string concatenation. For example many [sql flavors use `||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html)

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Thanks for telling this info

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let `hash` be the raw hash function, as you're referring to. You mentioned that the attacker knows `hash(message || length)`, but to be more precise, they know `hash(message || padding || length)`. Let `full_hash` be the proper hash with padding and length, i.e. `full_hash(message) = hash(message || padding || length)`.

You're correct that if the attacker knows `hash(message || padding || length)`, then they can't compute `hash(message || appended_data)`.

But they *can* compute `hash(message || padding || length || appended_data || actual_padding || actual_length)` which is equal to `full_hash(message || padding || length || appended_data)`, which may be enough for an attack. The inner `padding` and `length` become "garbage" which can be ignored depending on the attack scenario.

In order to carry out the attack, start from `hash(message || padding || length)` (i.e. the original hash), use it as the initial state for the hash, and then feed the remaining data (`appended_data || actual_padding || actual_length`).

Comment: You forgot the padding there.

Comment: @SEJPM I'm guessing "length" refers to "MD length padding" in this case.

Comment: Not convinced, that kind of derivation can only be made if you already know that the plaintext is extended by padding followed by the encoding of the length. Likely only persons that understand length attacks already know that this is the case. I think SEJPM makes a valid point and the answer should be extended or adjusted.

Comment: I don't think that mentioning padding helps understanding the issue, but I expanded my answer in an attempt to be more precise and clear.

Answer (score 3):

You should think of the attack as being directed *against the hash function as a whole*. What you are calling

$$\mathrm{hash}(\mbox{message} + \mbox{length})$$

is really

$$\mathrm{Hash}(\mbox{message})$$

where I've used the capitalization to distinguish the two. $\mathrm{Hash}$, not $\mathrm{hash}$, is the actual "hash function", and this is what is subject to attack - you're extending the length of *its* input, i.e. just "$\mathrm{message}$" here. And yes, the distinction between the two is important, and consequential to the security properties:

> All Merkle-Damgård based hash functions do have an upper limit, because appending the message length simplifies the security proof and the backdoor-resistance of the function and they usually use a fixed-length encoding of the length.

Hence, $\mathrm{hash}$ is actually an *internal part* of the hash function, not the hash function proper, despite appearances to the contrary. Its security properties are *not the same*.

Crypto is like that - seemingly-insignificant changes can have major effects. It's fussy. The "security landscape" in algorithm space is more like a smattering of isolated points or perhaps even a fractal, rather than a nice, smooth surface or connected volume, thus sensitive to small perturbations around any given point. It's an Art *par excellence*, and why one never trusts ciphers or other cryptographic items from anyone but the grand masters. All of them are beautiful works of art, and they should be marveled at with all the feeling of seeing a Picasso, or M.C. Escher's, or others such, and with just as much deep appreciation of the skilled and delicate hands that went into making them.