# Is this modification in Merkle-Damgård collision-resistant?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, merkle-damgaard

We modify Merkle-Damgård construction by setting $z_0:=L$ (the length of the message), computing $z_i:=h(z_{i-1}||x_i)$ for $i=1,...,B$ and defining $H(x):=z_B.$ Is this construction collision-resistant?

I think that it can not be collision resistant, because by adding the input length in the beginning after many steps two different messages may have the same output, but I can not find a counterexample to refute the assumption.

Collision resistant definition (from Katz&Lindell Introduction to Modern Cryptography): it is difficult to find $x$ and $x'$, with $x \neq x'$ such that $H(x)=H(x')$.

Comment: Yes, no, or less, depending on the definition of collision-resistant. Suggestion: write down the definition considered, and wonder if the attack in the question works per that definition. The answers to that [different question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1427/555) can help. If stuck, per our [policy on what's on-topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), add the definition of collision-resistant considered in the question, and explain where applying it is difficult.

Comment: Have you tried proving that it's collision resistant? Do you know whether $h$ is CR?

Comment: yes, h is collision resistant.

Comment: The standard way of proving a construction is CR (based on a CR primitive) is to show, given a collision with the construction, you can show a collision in the CR primitive.  Does that proof technique work in this case?  How does it break down?  That should show you how to construct a CR $h$ where your modified MD construction is not CR...

Comment: In my edition of K&L, definition 5.2 is much more complex than yours. In particular, it makes "difficult" something on the tune of: there exists no polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: @fgrieu: the problem with that definition is that no fixed hash function, such as SHA-3-512, can satisfy it (as there exists a simple program that will output a collision - we don't know what that program is, but it does exist)

Comment: Is there a way to obtain collisions of short length for some $h$? If there isn't, it should be CR since it takes exponential time to write out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Katz-Lindell said, assume there is a collision-resistant compression function such that it is possible to efficiently find some $L, x \in \{\ 0, 1\}^{n}$ such that $h(L,x) = L - n$. 
In this case, the hash of any message $y$ of length $L-n$ is equal to the hash of the message $(x \| y)$ of length $L$. 
**BUT, the question is**: 
How to show that *it is possible to construct a hash function with this property, assuming collision-resistant hash functions exists*?